# stops sidebar scrolling when its reach bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, sidebar

I am working on a site which has a sticky sidebar. The sidebar will only fix on a scrolling window.

The problem is, when I scroll window down and reach bottom of the page, the sidebar will overlap the footer because the sidebar is fixed.

I want, when the user reaches the bottom of the page, the sidebar to stop scrolling and, if user is scrolling top of the page, it should start scrolling again.

You can check my code below or you can check **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GsKJh/)**.

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){

        var contPos = $('.sidebar').offset().top;       

        var containerHeight = $('.container').height();

        var heightOfWindow = $('body').height();            
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (contPos < topOfWindow) {
                $('.sidebar').css('margin-top',''+topOfWindow+'px');

            }
    }); 


</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="sidebar">asd</div>
<div class="container">Contaier</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header{height:100px; text-align:center; font-size:35px; color:#000; background:#999;}
.container{overflow:auto; padding:15px; background:#CCC; height:1000px; margin:0 0 0 300px;}
.sidebar{width:300px; height:700px; float:left; background:red;}
.footer{height:100px; text-align:center; font-size:35px; color:#000; background:#999;}
```

Comment: why do this using javascript? it looks to me like you want to use something like `position:fixed` for the sidebar

Comment: "the sidebar to stop scrolling and, if user is scrolling top of the page, it should start scrolling again" - if it scroll then what do you mean by "fixed"..? where you trying to create something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GsKJh/1/)? i didn't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want that side bar will not exceeds footer when user reach bottom of the page ... and when user scrolling from bottom to top of the page then sidebar should start floating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll have to write a JS code that would detect if the sidebar is at the top, bottom or in the middle of the page. Then you could set a specific css class "bottom", "top",.. and set the right position between `fixed`/`absolute`.

Here is how I would have done it:

http://jsfiddle.net/w6G7Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the initial problem can be fixed quite easily by giving the sidebar's CSS class `position:absolute` and setting the `top` property rather than `margin-top`

css:

```
.sidebar{
    width:300px; 
    height:700px; 
    float:left; 
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

javascript:

```
if (contPos < topOfWindow) 
{
    $('.sidebar').css('top',topOfWindow+'px');
}
```

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg8nr/1/)

You will still have a problem when scrolling back up though.

Comment: thanks for help I want that side bar will not exceeds footer when user reach bottom of the page ... and when user scrolling from bottom to top oaf the page then sidebar should start floating.